# Using Visual Basic to make a SOAP call after importing a WSDL file

Tags: xml, vb.net, soap, wsdl

I was asked by an external company to communicate with then via a SOAP request. They gave me four files 00000001.WSDL, request.xml, response.xml and 00000001.pfx. I could load the WSDL file into SOAPUI and use the certificate in the SSL properties and run and get a response. I tried to replicate this in code using VB but have come to a stop.

Successfully imported my WSDL file into my VS2008 solution. How do I make a call to the server and get a response?

The WSDL file gives me these:

```
Public Class _PAM999AINPUT
          Inherits System.Object

Public Class _PAM999AOUTPUT
          Inherits System.Object

Public Class pam999n
          Inherits System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol

Public Class PAM999NCompletedEventArgs
          Inherits System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs

Public Delegate Sub PAM999NCompletedEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MySol.MyWebRef.PAM999NCompletedEventArgs)
```

My two xml files look like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:com-softwareag-entirex-rpc:COMMON">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:PAM999N>
         <_PAM999A-INPUT>
            <_PAM999A-I-USERNAME>Test User</_PAM999A-I-USERNAME>
         </_PAM999A-INPUT>
      </urn:PAM999N>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

< and

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xmm="http://namespace.softwareag.com/entirex/xml/mapping" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <m:PAM999NResponse xmlns:m="urn:com-softwareag-entirex-rpc:COMMON">
         <_PAM999A-OUTPUT>
            <_PAM999A-O-RESPONSE>HI  Test User        YOU HAVE INVOKED THE TEST MYCOMPANY SECURE WEBSERVICE ON (date & time)</_PAM999A-O-RESPONSE>
         </_PAM999A-OUTPUT>
      </m:PAM999NResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I've seen loads of examples but none with combinations of WSDL XML PFX & VB.NET

Some guidance needed please

Answer (score 0):

Try XML linq below.  An ampersand is valid in the second file so I had to replace with a special xml character

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim input1 As String = _
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:urn=""urn:com-softwareag-entirex-rpc:COMMON"">" & _
          "<soapenv:Header/>" & _
          "<soapenv:Body>" & _
             "<urn:PAM999N>" & _
                "<_PAM999A-INPUT>" & _
                   "<_PAM999A-I-USERNAME>Test User</_PAM999A-I-USERNAME>" & _
                "</_PAM999A-INPUT>" & _
             "</urn:PAM999N>" & _
          "</soapenv:Body>" & _
       "</soapenv:Envelope>"


        Dim input2 As String = _
       "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"" xmlns:xmm=""http://namespace.softwareag.com/entirex/xml/mapping"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">" & _
          "<SOAP-ENV:Header/>" & _
          "<SOAP-ENV:Body>" & _
             "<m:PAM999NResponse xmlns:m=""urn:com-softwareag-entirex-rpc:COMMON"">" & _
                "<_PAM999A-OUTPUT>" & _
                   "<_PAM999A-O-RESPONSE>HI  Test User        YOU HAVE INVOKED THE TEST MYCOMPANY SECURE WEBSERVICE ON (date U+0026 time)</_PAM999A-O-RESPONSE>" & _
                "</_PAM999A-OUTPUT>" & _
             "</m:PAM999NResponse>" & _
          "</SOAP-ENV:Body>" & _
       "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"


        Dim element1 As XElement = XElement.Parse(input1)
        Dim element2 As XElement = XElement.Parse(input2)

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you just using the Web Service wizard (as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/d9w023sx(v=vs.80).aspx) to point to the WSDL and have Visual Studio automatically generate the required proxy classes?  You don't have to mess around manually with those files.

Then it is a matter of simply calling code like this:-

```
Dim ws As MyWebService.SomeService

Dim input As New _PAM999AINPUT()
input._PAM999A-I-USERNAME = "jhweng"

Dim output As String = ws.pam999n(input)
Debug.WriteLine("Web service said: " & output)
```

The following Microsoft article is very good at walking you though creating a SOAP Web Service client.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5th1ba(v=vs.90).aspx